# How can I add an extra field in Drupal 8 menu Item. I want to add an extra image field

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

How can I add an extra field in Drupal 8 menu item? I want to add an extra image field so that I can use that to display along with menu.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Menu Item Extras module on Drupal.org projects site. https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras

But if you are looking for the harder way, you should manage differences in the rendering of menu items in the menu template, altering entity definition of `menu_link_content` entity using [hook_entity_type_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/8.5.x), altering `menu_link_content` form integrations such as `node` create\edit form, override default menu item create form controller (there is provided property bundle with value `menu_link_content` by the default).

It was not easy to extend menu item create/edit form using Field UI features because of the bug in Drupal core. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2903161
But for now, the issue is solved.

So for now, you can manage that situation as with usual entity type. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/222260/60214 or https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220463/60214

Answer (score 1):

You can add it through code and then run update.php or drush command to updatedb.

You can check answers here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205058/how-to-add-fields-to-menu-items

Also check comments because I had some problems with that and I've left solution in comments.